# Group two table with timestamps in common and sum amount for each month

Tags: php, sql

1st income and 2nd expense with date as timestamps in both and total of income and expense for each month,
now I want to get out put in a table as followed

```
Month | Income | Expense | Profit
```

Till now I am able to only group one table with amount as total, but I need a query which can handle both tables at same time.

My query is

```php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
    date_on,
    MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_on)) as expmonth,
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_on)) as expyear,
    sum(amount) as exp_total

    from finance_grdps_exp

    group by  expmonth,expyear order by date_on DESC")

    or die(mysql_error());  
    $no=0;   
    $countem = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {$no++;
            echo' 
            <tr class="gradeX">
                <td>'.
                $row['expmonth'].' '.$row['expyear'].'
                </td>
                <td>'.
                $row['exp_total'].'
                </td>
                <td>'.
                $row['income_total'].' /* not working as if now
                </td>
                <td>'.
                PROFIT.'/* not working as if now
                </td>
                </tr> 
                ';
                }
```

---

Guys Sample date base is ....

Income table ....

### Name| Income_date (timestamps) | income_amount

Exp Table

### Name|date_on (timestamps) |amount

Thx

Ruben thanks for reply .... but i am getting error

...in both cases i am getting error--- Every derived table must have its own alias ....

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_on)) as expmonth,
       YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_on)) as expyear,
       SUM(amount) as exp_total, 
       SUM(income_amount) as inc_total 
FROM(SELECT finance_grdps_exp.date_on AS date_on, 
            finance_grdps_exp.amount AS exp_amount, 
            0 AS inc_amount 
     UNION 
     SELECT finance_grdps_income.income_date AS date_on, 
            0 AS exp_amount, 
            finance_grdps_income.income_amount AS inc_amount) 
GROUP BY expyear, expmonth ORDER BY date_on DESC
```

Please Help

Comment: Can you show the database schema and some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have two tables finance_grdps_exp and finance_grdps_inc of following structure:

```
date_on | amount
```

1. If there are no two rows with same year and month encoded in date_on in one table, date_on contains only year and month i.e. other fields (day and time) are same for all rows.

   You can combine them with INNER JOIN construction:

   ```
   SELECT finance_grdps_exp.date_on AS date_on,
          finance_grdps_exp.amount AS exp_amount,
          finance_grdps_inc.amount AS inc_amount
   FROM finance_grdps_exp INNER JOIN finance_grdps_inc
   ON finance_grdps_exp.date_on = finance_grdps_inc.date_on
   ```

   Resulting structure is:

   ```
   date_on | exp_amount | inc_amount
   ```

   Then let's apply your idea to resulting structure:

   ```
   SELECT date_on,
          MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(finance_grdps_exp_and_inc.date_on)) as expmonth,
          YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(finance_grdps_exp_and_inc.date_on)) as expyear,
          SUM(finance_grdps_exp_and_inc.exp_amount) as exp_total,
          SUM(finance_grdps_exp_and_inc.inc_amount) as inc_total

   FROM (SELECT finance_grdps_exp.date_on AS date_on,
                finance_grdps_exp.amount AS exp_amount,
                finance_grdps_inc.amount AS inc_amount
   FROM finance_grdps_exp INNER JOIN finance_grdps_inc
   ON finance_grdps_exp.date_on = finance_grdps_inc.date_on) AS finance_grdps_exp_and_inc

   GROUP BY expyear, expmonth ORDER BY date_on DESC
   ```

   mysql_query gives us:

   ```
       [
         expmonth,
         expyear,
         exp_total /* expense per month */,
         inc_total /* income per month */
       ]
   ```

   To be sure in maximum performance of INNER JOIN statement 
   create index for date_on fields in both tables.
2. Other case (using UNION SELECT).

   ```
   SELECT MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(finance_grdps_exp_and_inc.date_on)) as expmonth,
          YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(finance_grdps_exp_and_inc.date_on)) as expyear,
          SUM(finance_grdps_exp_and_inc.exp_amount) as exp_total,
          SUM(finance_grdps_exp_and_inc.inc_amount) as inc_total
   FROM(SELECT finance_grdps_exp.date_on AS date_on,
          finance_grdps_exp.amount AS exp_amount,
          0 AS inc_amount 
          FROM finance_grdps_exp
        UNION 
        SELECT finance_grdps_inc.date_on AS date_on,
          0 AS exp_amount,
          finance_grdps_inc.amount AS inc_amount
          finance_grdps_inc) AS finance_grdps_exp_and_inc
   GROUP BY expyear, expmonth ORDER BY date_on DESC
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reply ...in both cases i am getting error--- Every derived table must have its own alias ....SELECT MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_on)) as expmonth,
       YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_on)) as expyear,
       SUM(amount) as exp_total,
       SUM(income_amount) as inc_total
FROM(SELECT finance_grdps_exp.date_on AS date_on,
       finance_grdps_exp.amount AS exp_amount,
       0 AS inc_amount
     UNION 
     SELECT finance_grdps_income.income_date AS date_on,
       0 AS exp_amount,
       finance_grdps_income.income_amount AS inc_amount)
GROUP BY expyear, expmonth ORDER BY date_on DESC

Comment: thanks for reply... but getting error in both cases ....Every derived table must have its own alias...

Comment: I have edited queries. May be new version will work. Please try.